# Simple python TCP server with sending command to communicate with esp32

Tags: python, tcp, esp32, python-sockets

I'm new to python programming. I want to create a simple TCP server working with an esp32. The idea of this is to send command *data = '{\"accel\",\"gyro\",\"time\":1}'* to esp32 via socket and then wait around 10ms for reply from esp32. I tried many examples but nothing works. ESP32 gets my message from this program but I can't receive message from esp32.

```
import socket

# bind all IP address
HOST = '192.168.137.93'
# Listen on Port 
PORT = 56606 
#Size of receive buffer
localhost=('0.0.0.0', 56606)   
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024    
# Create a TCP/IP socket
data = '{\"accel\",\"gyro\",\"time\":1}'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the host and port
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
# send data to server
s.send(bytearray(data, 'utf-8'))
s.serve_forever()
print('Listen for incoming connections')
sock.listen(1)
while True:

    client, addr = s.accept()

    while True:
        content = client.recv(1024)

        if len(content) ==0:
           break

        else:
            print(content)

    print("Closing connection")
    client.close()
```

I tried more and tried to use other code(see below). Now I get message back but on other port(I can track it by wireshark)

```
import socket

# Ip of local host
HOST = '192.168.137.93' 
# Connect to Port 
PORT = 56606 
#Size of send buffer   
BUFFER_SIZE = 4096
# data to sent to server
message = '{\"accel\",\"gyro\",\"time\":1}'
# Create a TCP/IP socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Connect to server
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
# send data to server
s.send(bytearray(message, 'utf-8'))
# Receive response from server
data = ""       
while len(data) < len(message):
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
# Close connection
print ('Server to Client: ' , data)
s.close()
```

I don't use both of these codes together. 
Any hints?

Comment: The content of your `data` variable (or `message` variable) looks invalid -- if that's supposed to be a JSON value, it's not. What does the code on your esp32 look like?

Comment: This doesn’t seem right to so completely separate the sending from the receiving - that’s not going to work. After you’ve sent the command to the ESP32 you need to keep that __same__ socket `s` open to receive the response.